# VirtualBox to browse a backend server listen on specific port

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

VirtualBox and Vagrant installed on my Windows.

machine up...

```
vagrant up
;
;
homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
;
;
```

I browse successfully to my site as follows:
http://test02.app:8000

My 'Homestead.yaml' file contains the following sites:

```
sites:
    - map: test01.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/test01
    - map: test02.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/test02
    - map: test03.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/test03
```

My windows hosts file contains the following:

```
127.0.0.1   test01.app
127.0.0.1   test02.app
127.0.0.1   test03.app
```

I have a basic HTTP server using Node.js which installed on this folder (test02/backend), that provide some image editor services (dl, upload, img etc).

The server listen on port 9006.

So I suppose to browse as follows: http://test02.app:8000:9006

Of course this can't work.

What will be the syntax of the url of my site using this port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server you want to reach is listening on port 9006, you can directly access it with http://test02.app:9006 (make sure the server is listening on 0.0.0.0 and not only 127.0.0.1)

You will reach 8000 if you want to reach the web server, the web server can forward request to another server (that will be some configuration from your webserver)